# How to log exception stack trace using stackdriver in .net-core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, stackdriver

I have setup stackdriver logging on a .net core 2.0 project and it seems to work fine. There is one issue while logging exceptions - stack trace or any exception related info is not getting logged.

The below piece of code throws a null exception and `.LogError` method is used to log the exception - it takes an exception object as a parameter.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
    StackdriverLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("ImageCompressInfo");
    try {
        throw new NullReferenceException("null");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        StackdriverLogger.LogError(ex, "Exception in configure 2", null);
    }

    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseGoogleExceptionLogging();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The following log is generated. As you can see there is no exception related info - not even the `string argument` passed while throwing the exception.

[image: Stackdriver log]

Am I using the library correctly? Is there a way to capture the entire stack trace using .net-core logging and stackdriver?

**Edit** - Unhandled Errors are caught and reported to Error Reporting. The same errors are also present in Logs with complete stack trace. **It seems when using `.LogError()` function, errors do not forward to Error Reporting.**

Comment: Your usage seems correct to me.  Have you tried Error Reporting to see if that gets you the entire stack trace? (I apologize, but I'm not terribly familiar with .NET)

Comment: @YuriGrinshteyn - it seems unhandled errors are logged with the exception trace and present in Error reporting. Using `.LogError` does not even add an error to Error reporting or stacktrace.